# Flutter: How to store and retrieve a single item/object from Sembast database

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am building a Fruit shopping cart and I want it to be persistent. I have successfully implemented persistence for the list of fruits using Sembast, but I have not succeeded in doing so for the cart.

How can I properly store and retrieve a single record of Cart object from the database?

Here is my code:

Cart Entity

```
class Cart extends Equatable {
  final Map<int, int> cartList;

  Cart({this.cartList});

  static Cart fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CartFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CartToJson(this);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [cartList];
}
```

Cart.g.dart

```
Cart _$CartFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Cart(
    cartList: (json['cartList'] as Map<String, dynamic>)?.map(
      (k, e) => MapEntry(int.parse(k), e as int),
    ),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$CartToJson(Cart instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'cartList': instance.cartList?.map((k, e) => MapEntry(k.toString(), e)),
    };
```

My Database Repository

```
class DatabaseHandler extends PlantsRepository {
  static const String CART_STORE_NAME = 'cart__';
 
  final _cartStore = intMapStoreFactory.store(CART_STORE_NAME);

  Future<Database> get _database async => await FrutsDatabase.instance.database;

  @override
  Future<Cart> getPlantsFromCart() async {
    final snap = await _cartStore.find(await _database);

    final carts = snap.map((e) => Cart.fromJson(e.value)).toList();

    return carts.elementAt(0);
  }
  
  @override
  Future insertPlantIntoCart(Cart cart) async {
    await _cartStore.add(await _database, cart.toJson());
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get a record is using its key (or id, whatever name fits). You get the key during add. Here is a slight modification of your `DatabaseHandler` class:

```dart
class DatabaseHandler extends PlantsRepository {
  /// Get a cart by id
  Future<Cart> getCart(int id) async {
    var map = await _cartStore.record(id).get(await _database);
    return map == null ? null : Cart.fromJson(map);
  }

  /// Add a cart and returns its id
  Future<int> addCart(Cart cart) async {
    return await _cartStore.add(await _database, cart.toJson());
  }
}
```

That could be used like this:

```dart
// Insert the cart
var cartId = await databaseHandler.addCart(cart);

// Read the cart
cart = await databaseHandler.getCart(cartId);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Your solution was helpful.

Comment: BTW, still cartStore.record was and still efficient, need to find by using String method would be convienient as I get data from firebase, I can store the key as same as to SemBast.